# What is it called when you subtract multiples of 360 degrees?

Tags: geometry, terminology, angle

When  you divide a vector by its magnitude to get a unit vector, there's a verb for that:  you are "normalizing" the vector.

Similarly, is there a verb for when you subtract multiples of $360$ degrees to find a coterminal angle?

E.g., if I start with the angle $736.4^o$, and subtract $720^o$ to get the coterminal angle $16.4^o$, is there a verb for what I just did?

This coterminal angle can be found with the modulo function - $\text{mod}(736.4,\ 360)\ $- but "modulo-ing" is probably not the verb I'm looking for.

Comment: Some might call this *taking the principal value* or something similar

Comment: I'd throw in: operating modulo 360 (mod 360). You may also look up "congruence".

Comment: You can say "reducing modulo 360"

Comment: you're using the wrapped version of the angle. In highfalutin language, you're working with equivalence classes of angles modulo 360 degrees (or modulo a full rotation).

Answer (score 1):

I'd be fine with “**normalizing**”. The general idea of normalization is that you have a definition of what you consider normal (the normal form), and a class of transformations to turn other things to that normal form. For vectors, normal is unit length, and transformations are scaling. For angles, picking 0° − 360° (or −180° − +180°) as normal range, and addition / subtraction of full turns as transformations, makes just as much sense.

I might also call this the “**canonical representation**” of the angle, but I can't think of a good verb to go with that. To me this terminology has a connotation of equivalence classes lurking in the background, which is quite applicable here.

If you are looking for verbs and don't like normalization, the “**reduction modulo** 360°” which Jair Taylor wrote in a comment likely allows subsequent usage to only use “reduction” for the operation.